# Error 691 VPN Windows Server 2011 SBS

Tags: routes, vpn, dmz, windows-sbs

Our Network is build on a ESXi 5 which is connected on the second NIC with an IPCop. On the first NIC it is connected through a switch with all my clients.

On the ESXi i have a Windows Server SBS 2011 Standard with 2 NIC's. One for my private network and the other to get connected to the internet.

I've managed to get this working with RRAS but somehow i cant connect through VPN to my server. I allways get the 691 Error. I use PPTP as protocoll and i'm forwarding the needed ports... I even disabled the windows firewall for testing.

The error is telling me to check if i typed in the correct username or password or the RAS server may not allow the authenticationprotocoll... But in my RAS Settings i activated the pptp port for ras and routing.

Any help on this ?

Comment: i solved it myself... my dyndns was pointing to the wrong host... god i feel stupid right now...